# Angular2/JavaScript - Increment/Decrement by 1 on (click)

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to Increment/Decrement when the user presses the add button, then update the amount value accordingly. I've tried a couple of times, but unfortunately I was not successful!

Here is the code:

```
  addToCart(){
  this.amount = 1;
  }

  addItem(){
    this.amount++;
    console.log('plus is : '+this.amount++)
  }

  removeItem(){
   this.amount--;
   console.log('plus is : '+this.amount--)
  }
```

HTML:

```
   <div (click)="addToCart()">ADD</div>
   <div (click)="removeItem()" class="btnSign">-</div> 
   <div>{{amount}}</div> 
   <div (click)="addItem()" class="btnSign">+</div>
```

Comment: Is your JS code in a controller? How is your controller being included in your view?

Comment: Yes! it is outside of the constructor()

Comment: Btw, even if the current code worked, it would always increment/decrement the amount by 2, since you're using post-increment (the `++`) before `console.log` and also within the `console.log` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was in using ++

```
export class HelloWorld {
public amount:number;

addToCart(){
this.amount = 1;
}

addItem(){
this.amount=this.amount+1;
console.log('plus is : '+this.amount)
}

removeItem(){
this.amount=this.amount-1;
console.log('plus is : '+this.amount)
}


}
```

[here is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a0Q0HLReyNk6ZbTrHeuq?p=preview)

Comment: Your solution does not work if we have duplicate buttons... it will keep incrementing/decrementing all the other buttons together