# How can I translate this JS to Angular2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am willing to implement an **add to cart** button in my Angular2 app, currently I can do it in JavaScript/Jquery; however, I don't know how to achieve that is Angular2.

Here is a JSfiddle of the working code:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
           $(".up").on('click',function(){
           var $incdec = $(this).prev();
           if ($incdec.val() < $(this).data("max")) {
            $incdec.val(parseInt($incdec.val())+1);
           }
       });

     $(".down").on('click',function(){
        var $incdec = $(this).next();
        if ($incdec.val() > $(this).data("min")) {
          $incdec.val(parseInt($incdec.val())-1);
        }
       });
      });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mail2asik/M8JTP/

I want to do the same, but in Angular2.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the reason to do that?

Comment: I answered similar question here: [Angular2/JavaScript - Increment/Decrement by 1 on (click)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094784/angular2-javascript-increment-decrement-by-1-on-click/37100851#37100851)

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez what's the reason of not to do it? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative answer would be to declare the text input as a variable and update it "directly"

### HTML "Component template"

```html
<tr>
   <td>
     <input type="button" (click)="dec(elem)" value="Down"/>
     <input type="text" #elem value="0"/>
     <input type="button" (click)="inc(elem)" value="Up"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

### JS

```
      inc(elem)
      {
        var nItem = parseInt(elem.value);
        if(nItem < 5)
        {
          nItem +=1;
          elem.value = nItem;
        }
      }

      dec(elem)
      {
        var nItem = parseInt(elem.value);
        if(nItem > 0)
        {
          nItem -=1;
          elem.value = nItem;
        }
      }
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vJAk9IIxLx7dKH0G8l8f?p=preview) is a working Plunker ^^

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not work if you have more than one field, i.e up/down

Comment: After some modifications, I was able to make your solution works!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple javascript to achieve that functionality.

```
export class HelloWorld {
  public amount: number = 1;

  addToCart() {
    this.amount = 1;
  }



  addItem() {
    if (this.amount == 5) {
      this.amount = 5;
    }
    else {
      this.amount = this.amount + 1;
    };
  }



  removeItem() {
    if (this.amount == 0) {
      this.amount = 0;


    } else {
      this.amount = this.amount - 1;
    };
}


}
```

html:

```
  <button (click)="addToCart()">ADD item</button>

  <br>
  <br>
   <button (click)="removeItem()" class="btnSign">Down</button> 
 <input type="text" class="incdec" value="{{amount}}"/>
 <button (click)="addItem()" class="btnSign">Up</button>
```

[Here is the example in the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kS1MHelAftSq3T1c1bCZ?p=preview)

Comment: It is a duplicate question as well, I answered both questions.